# I don't need ip address on text box

Tags: laravel, validation, textbox

It is very easy to validate IP address for a text box in laravel so that it will accepts only IP address. So that what my requirement is while validating text box at form in laravel,It should not accept only ip address but can accept other. How can I do that ? I will be very grateful for that and want to say thanks in advance.

Comment: You can create your custom validation rule https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#custom-validation-rules.

Comment: What code do you have so far?

Comment: What do you mean with other?

Comment: Means if i put other than IP address in text box ,it should accept.